# batch insertion of millions of records on the pre-existing nodes

Tags: neo4j

i am going to insert 100M relationships on the 3M existing node using batchinserter in neo4j. but i have no idea how to make pointer to existing node as i have not their ID on the graph.as all exiting example on the web for batchinserter are for conditions that there is some references to the start and end nodes.
i tried to use IndexManager for finding start and end nodes but it only work on regular GraphDatabaseService instances not on batchinserter :(

```
IndexManager index = Inserter.index();
```

furthermore i have an index on the feature that i want to get nodes by it's value.
thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: sorry " get nodes by its value."

Comment: you can still get nodes by id in the batch-inserter, just iterate from id 0 to the maximum id in your database.

Answer (score 1):

BatchInserter API has support for indexes, see http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.1/org/neo4j/index/lucene/unsafe/batchinsert/LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider.html.